# remove a Subscriber from a Email Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is what i use to add a subscriber and i have no problem adding

```sql
INSERT INTO SubscribersForEmail([To],Cc,ReplyTo,TeamLetter,ReportName,Comment)
 VALUES();
```

When i try and delete a subscriber im using the option below and i keep getting a syntax error. Can you tell me what im doing wrong Im i using the Delete correctly

```sql
 DELETE FROM SubscribersForEmail([To],Cc,ReplyTo,TeamLetter,ReportName,Comment)
 VALUES();
```

Comment: You don't provide `VALUES` to a `DELETE` statement, you use a `FROM` and limit the rows with a `WHERE`. Take the time to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or even a basic [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) and you'll instantly see your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for deleting a row from a table is:

```
delete from SubscribersForEmail
    where <some condition should go here>;
```